# make always rebuilds all targets

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, geany, ubuntu-15.04

On

> make

both the compile and run targets are rebuilt, even though **no changes** are made to the file One.c

```
all: compile run

compile: One.c
    gcc One.c -o One

run: One
    ./One

.PHONY: run
```

I am using Ubuntu-15.04 as OS, and Geany as editor.

One.c contains only one print statement, "hello world".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `make` it will try to build first rule in makefile (`all`), which depends on targets `compile` and `run`.

`run` is phony and will be run anyway. `compile` is non-phony, but there is no file named `compile`, so make will try to build this target (expecting it to produce `compile` file, but it wouldn't).

You need to add `One` non-phony target and build your binary here, e.g.:

```
all: compile run

compile: One

One: One.c
    gcc One.c -o One

run: One
    ./One

.PHONY: run compile
```